# django get all running/pending celery task for current django user

Tags: celery, django-celery

Is there any pythonic way to get all running/pending celery tasks for current loggedin django user? Pseudo code for what I am trying:

```
    @celery.task
    def process_task(user, task_to_do):
        #get all running or pending(queued) task for current user
        user_tasks = user.get_task(status=PENDING or status=STARTED)
        if not user_task:
            #allow user to schedule additional task
            process....
        else:
            return "Your previous tasks is already running"
```

Answer (score 3):

That's in general a tricky task.

> First you need to implement [inspecting of workers](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html?highlight=revoke#inspecting-workers)

```
inspector = app.control.inspect()
scheduled = inspector.scheduled()
reserved = inspector.reserved()
active = inspector.active()
```

Celery will get them from your broker. The point is - broker does not store information about user, so you need to add `user` it to task **kwargs**.

`user_task.delay(user=user)`

Than you'll be able to filter results from thees functions by kwarg `user` in result:

    `[{'worker1.example.com':
        [{'eta': '2010-06-07 09:07:52', 'priority': 0,
          'request': {
            'name': 'tasks.usertask',
            'id': '1a7980ea-8b19-413e-91d2-0b74f3844c4d',
            'args': '[]',
            'kwargs': '{`**'user':'7'**`}'}},
 ...`

> The problem here - it will be slow.

Comment: Thats true. Let me explain how i did it. My app manages custom task status as well, so I decide perhaps storing task status to database can be better option here. (I created a model called TaskUser)

is_task_in_progress = False
for task in TaskUser.objects.filter(user=map.owner).exclude(status='SUCCESS').exclude(status="FAILURE").all():
        celery_job = current_app.AsyncResult(task.task_id)
        if celery_job.ready():
            ...
        else:
            is_task_in_progress = True